# Run code block in parallel while streaming data

Tags: python, websocket, async-await

I have a code block to streaming online data, but in the mean while, I want another block to run from time to time for analysis.

```
class steaming_price():
def on_open(ws):
    print('opened connection')


def on_close(ws):
    print('closed connection')


def on_message(ws, message):
    global closes, in_position, current_time
    print('received message')
    json_message = json.loads(message)
    #pprint.pprint(json_message)

    candle = json_message['k'] #all kline data
    is_candle_closed = candle['x'] #if its closed
    close = candle['c'] #the Close Price

    #Print the Close Price
    if is_candle_closed:
        print("candle closed at {}".format(close))
        closes.append(float(close))
        current_time.append(datetime.datetime.now())
        print(f"Time:{datetime.datetime.now()} Close:{close}")


ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCKET, on_open=on_open, on_close=on_close, on_message=on_message)
ws.run_forever()
```

The following should run every 1 minutes to do analysis

```
class strategy():
    def __init__(self):
        self.closes = deque(maxlen=500)

    def strategy(self, data):
        self.macd, self.macd_signal, self.macd_hist = talib.MACD(data, fastperiod=12, slowperiod=26, signalperiod=9)
        return self.macd, self.macd_signal, self.macd_hist
```

First block of code would take data each second.
I would like to have the second block of code run in parallel every 1 minute to do analysis. For example, calculate 20 bar Moving Average and issue a buy order.

I thought about async, but it only run once(I couldn't get it to work either).

Any ideas? Much appriciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy solution would be to check on new message arrival how much time passed since last message was received and then if it's longer than 1 minute, do analysis on in the same function.

Another solution that you mentioned would require using [asyncio websockets library](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html):

server:

```
import asyncio
import json
from random import random

import websockets


async def hello(websocket, _):
    while True:
        value = random() * 50 + 50
        value = json.dumps({"v": value})
        await websocket.send(value)
        print(f"sent {value}")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


start_server = websockets.serve(hello, "localhost", 8080)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

client:

```
import asyncio
import json
from collections import deque

import websockets

q = deque(maxlen=5)

async def calc_sum():
    while True:
        data = list(q)
        print(f"sum {sum(data)}")
        await asyncio.sleep(3.6)

async def hello():
    uri = "ws://localhost:8080"
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        while True:
            value = await websocket.recv()
            value = json.loads(value)
            print(f"recv {value}")
            q.append(value['v'])

event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
event_loop.create_task(calc_sum())
event_loop.run_until_complete(hello())
```